# Attaching a base 64 encoded PDF to RestRequest Email using MailGun (C#)

Tags: c#, rest, base64, attachment, email-attachments

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this? The TestDataPdf begins with `data:application/pdf;filename=generated.pdf;base64,` and as a result, I am removing the Substring.

```
public static IRestResponse SendEmail(Nurse newNurse)
    {
      byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(newNurse.TestDataPdf.Substring(51));
      var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MAIL-GUN");
      RestClient client = new RestClient();
      client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");
      client.Authenticator =
          new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
                                      "xxxxxx");
      RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

      request.AddParameter("domain", "xxxx", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
      request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
      request.AddParameter("from", "<test@test.com>");
      request.AddParameter("to", $"{newNurse.RecruiterEmail}");
      request.AddParameter("subject", "New Skills Assessment Test");
      request.AddParameter("application/pdf", bytes, ParameterType.RequestBody);
      request.AddParameter("text", "test");
      // request.AddParameter("application/pdf", bytes, ParameterType.RequestBody);
      // request.AddFile("attachment", Path.Combine(pdflocation, fileName));

      request.Method = Method.POST;
      return client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
      request.AddFileBytes("attachment", bytes, "test", "application/pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
request.AddFileBytes("attachment", bytes, "test", "application/pdf");
```